# How to Print another classes information in different package + class

Tags: java, class, object, printing, attributes

I have these 2 classes in each of its own packages too

```
package app; 
import data.Sukka;

public class Kauppa { 
public static void main(String[] args) { 
Sukka sukka=new Sukka(); 
sukka.setId(1);
sukka.setKoko(22); 
sukka.setVari("musta"); 
sukka.setMateriaali("kangas");
sukka.setHinta("20eur");
tulostaSukka(sukka); 




} 
private static void tulostaSukka(Sukka sukka) 
{ // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
    System.out.println("Sukan id:"+sukka.getId());
    System.out.println("Sukan koko:"+sukka.getKoko()); 
    System.out.println("Sukan väri:"+sukka.getVari()); 
    System.out.println("Sukan materiaali:"+sukka.getMateriaali()); 
    System.out.println("Sukan hinta:"+sukka.getHinta()); 
}
}



     package data;

public class Sukka {
private int id;
private String vari;
private int koko;
private String materiaali;
private String hinta;
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getVari() {
    return vari;
}
public void setVari(String vari) {
    this.vari = vari;
  }
  public int getKoko() {        
    return koko;
   }
   public void setKoko(int koko) {
    this.koko = koko;
  }
   public String getMateriaali() {
    return materiaali;
}
public void setMateriaali(String materiaali) {
    this.materiaali = materiaali;
}
public String getHinta() {
    return hinta;
}
public void setHinta(String hinta) {
    this.hinta = hinta;
}
}
```

---

This is made so it shows the list of koko, väri etc etc.
I should create 3class in new package which would just print the attribute of sukka at once and so you would be able to choose which attribute you want it to print.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the various fields you just need to get the Class object from the class as follows

```
Class c = Sukko.getClass()
    c.getFields()
```

And then if you want to give the user the option to select which field should be displayed you will have to look at the reflections API

Comment: Hmm yea I still can't get it to work. I'am just a student and don't really catch up what I should put in there to get the getClass working. Tried lots of things already and things that eclipse and java recommend also.

Comment: Whichever class you wish to get details about u can call the .getClass() method on it. For example if you have a class Employee in com.dept package then import com.dept.Employee in your class and in the code use Employee.getClass() Then u can access the various methods of the class and properties of the class

Comment: Thank you for your help. I've made it this way for now,
I get the info "väri" etc printer but it only shows:null

 private static void tulostaTulostin(Tulostin tulostin) 
 { // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
  System.out.println("Sukan 
väri:"+Sukka.getClass("väri"));
  System.out.println("Sukan 
koko:"+Sukka.getClass("koko"));
  System.out.println("Sukan 
materiaali:"+Sukka.getClass("materiaali"));
  System.out.println("Sukan 
hinta:"+Sukka.getClass("hinta"));